# How to process multiple parquet files in parallel using Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing, databricks

I am using Azure Databricks and i'm new to Pyspark and big data.

Here is my problem:

I have several parquet files in a directory on azure databricks.
I want to read these files to a pyspark dataframe and use the drop duplicates method to remove duplicate rows - a QA check.
I then want to overwrite these files in the same directory after dropping the duplicates.

Currently, I am using a for loop to loop over each parquet file in the directory. However, this is an inefficient way of doing things. I was wondering if there is a way to process these parquet files in parallel to save computational time. If so how do I need to change my code.

Here is the code:

```
for parquet_file_name in dir:
     df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferschema", "false").parquet('{}/{}'.format(dir,parquet_file_name))
     df.dropDuplicates().write.mode('overwrite').parquet('{}/{}'.format(dir,parquet_file_name)
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than reading in one file at a time in a for loop, just read in the entire directory like so.

```
 df = spark.read \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("inferschema", "false").parquet(dir)


df.dropDuplicates().write.mode('overwrite').parquet(dir)
```

The data will now be read all at once as intended. If you want to change the number of files wrote out, use `coalesce` command before the `.write` function like so: `df.dropDuplicates().coalesce(4).write.mode('overwrite').parquet(dir)`.

Comment: Caveat: Spark cannot write a dataframe to the same directory as its source. Spark reads lazily, and `mode('overwrite')` will destroy the underlying data that the dataframe represents.

Comment: @CharlieFlowers I don't believe you are correct about Spark being unable to write to the same directory as it's source. It may not be a good practice, but the above function works as intended.

Comment: Are you sure? It may be file system dependent, but using Spark 2.4.3:

>>> df = spark.read \
...     .option("header", "true") \
...     .option("inferschema", "false").parquet("tst_parquet")

>>> df.dropDuplicates().write.mode('overwrite').parquet("tst_parquet")
20/01/03 18:06:35 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/Users/charlie/tst_parquet/part-00003-fcdf8911-53f0-4139-868b-81048e20b896-c000.snappy.parquet does not exist
It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate ...

Comment: @CharlieFlowers Ah I admit it may not work with reading from a file system like hdfs / dbfs. I tested it using a file in S3 and it worked. I also tested with Spark 2.4.3.